# What is the execution error when run query in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am querying logs in Kibana which connects to Elasticsearch cluster in the backend.

When I query logs in `Discovery` tab in Kibana, sometimes I see a popup error dialog with below exceptions. I can't find anything wrong in the backend logs.

```
search_phase_execution_exception


Error
    at Fetch._callee3$ (https://kibana.crms.myzeller.dev/36063/bundles/core/core.entry.js:6:59535)
    at l (https://kibana.crms.dev/36063/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:380:1740520)
    at Generator._invoke (https://kibana.crms.dev/36063/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:380:1740273)
    at Generator.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (https://kibana.crms.dev/36063/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:380:1740877)
    at fetch_asyncGeneratorStep (https://kibana.crms.dev/36063/bundles/core/core.entry.js:6:52652)
    at _next (https://kibana.crms.myzeller.dev/36063/bundles/core/core.entry.js:6:52968)
```

Answer (score 0):

is there more in your Elasticsearch and/or Kibana logs around the same time you are seeing this? there should be, and it'll help explain what the issue is